# Assigning a User Control to a Tab Item

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

I am trying to assign a usercontrol named Analysis to 2 Tab Items dynamically. However both tab items have a different structure and so i Have 2 assigning functions to populate both Tab Items by passing different data to the same user control.

```
<TabItem  Header="Ambiguities" Style="{DynamicResource AnalysisTabItem}" >
     <AnalysisControls:Analysis ></AnalysisControls:Analysis>
</TabItem>
<TabItem x:Name="tcer"  Style="{DynamicResource AnalysisTabItem}" MouseLeftButtonDown="TCERLOAD" >
     <TabItem.Header >
         <Button  Click="TCERLOADButton_Click">
              <Button.Template>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                        <Label>TCER</Label>
                   </ControlTemplate>
              </Button.Template>
         </Button>
     </TabItem.Header>
<AnalysisControls:Analysis></AnalysisControls:Analysis>
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Now I want the second tabitem to be populated on button click event. So this is what I am using to assign it. The first Tabitem gets autmatically populated on initialization.

```
private void TCERLOADButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        AnalysisViewModel a1 = new AnalysisViewModel();
        tcer.DataContext = a1.GetInstance1();
}
```

However it is not giving me the necessary results. Please help in getting through this.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to do here. It sounds like you want to display the exact same instance of UserControl in two separate places in the UI, which is not possible. You can either display the same instance of the UserControl in a single location and toggle how it's displayed with something like a `ContentTemplate`, or you can display two copies of the UserControl and have them share the same `DataContext` (data layer) that sits behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to UserControls in XAML much like constructors,

Not very clear what you are trying to do here so hard to give solution,